# Difference between rake assets:precompile:all and rake assets:precompile:primary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, asset-pipeline

We are using Rails 3 as our application. Compiling assets with `rake assets:precompile:all` takes quite a long time but with `rake assets:precompile:primary` it runs a bit faster

What is the difference between them? Can I just use `primary`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just use `:primary`. I believe `:all` compiles both non digest and digest assets while `:primary` compiles only digest assets. Digest assets are the assets with the checksum added to the name.